# How to wrap a Text value with quotes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have some broken Haskell code and have never even heard of Haskell before now.

The code is generating a DB query string and is failing to properly quote the identifiers.

So I simply want to put quotes around the identifiers.

Here is the existing code:

(this part in a separate file):

```
data PgArg = PgArg {
  pgaName :: Text
, pgaType :: Text
, pgaReq  :: Bool
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

(then the broken part in another file):

```
    unwords [
         "_args_record AS (",
         "SELECT * FROM " <> (if isObject then "json_to_record" else "json_to_recordset") <> "($1)",
         "AS _(" <> intercalate ", " ((\a -> pgaName a <> " " <> pgaType a) <$> pgArgs) <> ")",
     ")"]
```

I tried a few hacks, ultimately winding up with:

```
    unwords [
         "_args_record AS (",
         "SELECT * FROM " <> (if isObject then "json_to_record" else "json_to_recordset") <> "($1)",
         "AS _(" <> intercalate ", " ((\a -> (["\""] ++ (pgaName a) ++ ["\""]) <> " " <> pgaType a) <$> pgArgs) <> ")",
     ")"]
```

So basically I just changed:

```
pgaName a
```

To:

```
(["\""] ++ (pgaName a) ++ ["\""])
```

-- Anyway it fails with a type mismatch

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Text'
    * In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(pgaName a)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely `(pgaName a) ++ ["\""]'
      In the first argument of `(<>)', namely
        `(["\""] ++ (pgaName a) ++ ["\""])'
```

Any ideas how to fix this correctly?

Comment: Use `"\"" <> pgaName a <> "\""`

Comment: @4castle - that works thanks, do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: Aside from the bug, this code appears to be of rather low quality. Splicing strings together by hand is a terrible way to construct database queries! Haskell has several libraries available to do the job properly.

Comment: @dfeuer - tell it to the author [PostgREST](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You faced the problem because `(++)` operates on lists (`[]`), and while `String`s are just `[Char]`, `Text` is not.

Fortunately, there is generic append operator coming from `Monoid` class called `(<>)`. So, as @4castle said, just use `"\"" <> pgaName a <> "\""` to concatenate `Text`s.